# How to force next day if it's past certain time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have slight issue where i allow people to select any day from today to +1 Month.

I do that like this:

```
$('#book_table_calendar').datepicker(
    {
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+1M",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 1
    }
);
```

How would i tell datepicker that if current day time is at 21:00 (24h time format) then we start +1 month from tomorrow?

*Example:*
Todays datetime: 25/08/2013 21:00
Datepicker should show first active day as 26/08/2013

Should i use some sort of math function and return it to minDate or is there some other way?

Hope it's understandable enough. If not please ask for specifics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could find if its more than 9pm and set minDate to 1 instead of 0. For example,

```
var startDate = 0;   //default
//get current time from the server preferably
//using js here for demo
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
if(currentHour > 20) startDate = 1;  //set currentHour == 21 if you want this only if its 9pm
```

Then in your initialization:

```
$('#book_table_calendar').datepicker(
    {
        minDate: startDate,
        maxDate: "+1M",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 1
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm i thought that i probably do this way, thanks for example :) I'll take it from here.